# Flushing CloudFront's cache when S3 files are deleted

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have set up S3 with CloudFront as my CDN. As you know, when you upload files to S3 bucket, they are pushed to all CloudFront's edge locations and cached for best performance.

If I delete files from S3 they remain in CDN's cache and are still being served to the end-users. How to prevent this behavior? I want CloudFront to serve only the files that are actually available in the S3 storage.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can [invalidate](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) objects on Cloudfront using the API or the Console. When doing this, the files get deleted from the Cloudfront edge locations.